# How to get documents when authentication is required in the rules

Tags: firebase, delphi, google-cloud-firestore

I defined my rules in Firestore as below:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

I'm using Delphi's REST Client palette components to get the data, without the rule defined above I can read the data, but when I configure it to require authentication I can't get it.

I read this documentation:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/use-rest-api

Which led me to this other documentation:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/auth/

But I didn't understand how to generate the token property.
[image]

Comment: Have you tried to use the Firebase Open Source Library for Delphi FB4D?
https://github.com/SchneiderInfosystems/FB4D or from GetIt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know the tool you use and what are its capabilities. I found some interesting materials that might be helpful in this case:

[Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WtYzHTXHBp0) - this friendly shows the mechanism generally and Node.js implementation.

[Document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens) - here you might find all possibilities to create custom tokens as well on third party tools which I suppose you are using.

I hope it will help!